# Emails are not received on any email account except Gmail and Hotmail

Tags: domain-name-system, php, email

We have developed a web app using PHP 5.0 and MySQL 5.0. It runs on Apache on a Linux Redhat. It has a feature by which, the app sends email to the user's registered email address using mail() function.

Emails (sent from our server) are received only for GMail or Hotmail email account. It is not receiving for Yahoo or Rediffmail other email account.

Any idea of where to start debugging this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is probably not the actual sender of the eamil.

Check the email server (sendmail, exim, etc.) log files (on debian, logs are in /var).

Check the admin@ or postmaster@ email box for non-delivery notices.

Check if our ISP is publishing RDNS for your server IP with the wrong domain name.

Although less likely, check your domain's SPF at your registrar.