# Mailgun emails are rejected everywhere but on Gmail

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-bounces, verification

### My problem and Mailgun logs

I've "setup and verified" (see **context**) my sending domain with Mailgun, so I could use it to deliver my contact/order forms via Mailgun API: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

After successful verification (according to Mailgun) emails get delivered to Gmail addresses only though. Those are error logs provided by Mailgun for other email providers:

```
{
  "severity": "temporary",
  "tags": [],
  "storage": {
    "url": "https://so.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/mail.itvar.cz/messages/***",
    "key": "***"
  },
  "delivery-status": {
    "tls": true,
    "mx-host": "mx1.seznam.cz",
    "attempt-no": 2,
    "description": null,
    "session-seconds": 2.4669690132141113,
    "retry-seconds": 900,
    "code": 451,
    "message": "451 4.4.8 Unroutable email address.",
    "certificate-verified": true
  },
  "recipient-domain": "seznam.cz",
  "event": "failed",
  "campaigns": [],
  "reason": "generic",
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-routed": null,
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-system-test": false,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "log-level": "warn",
  "timestamp": 1473673115.668517,
  "envelope": {
    "transport": "smtp",
    "sender": "postmaster@mail.itvar.cz",
    "sending-ip": "209.61.151.224",
    "targets": "***@seznam.cz"
  },
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "***@gmail.com",
      "message-id": "20160912092829.59867.45844.82A5D054@mail.itvar.cz",
      "from": "redakce@itvar.cz",
      "subject": "Tvar / Objednávka předplatného poštou"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "***@gmail.com",
      "***@seznam.cz",
      "***@gmail.com"
    ],
    "size": 20723
  },
  "recipient": "***@seznam.cz",
  "id": "***"
}
```

TLDR: `451 4.4.8 Unroutable email address.`

```
{
  "severity": "permanent",
  "tags": [],
  "storage": {
    "url": "https://so.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/mail.itvar.cz/messages/***",
    "key": "***"
  },
  "delivery-status": {
    "tls": false,
    "mx-host": "postak.satoya.cz",
    "attempt-no": 1,
    "description": null,
    "session-seconds": 2.6076178550720215,
    "code": 505,
    "message": "505 Your domain has no DNS/MX entries",
    "certificate-verified": false
  },
  "recipient-domain": "itvar.cz",
  "event": "failed",
  "campaigns": [],
  "reason": "generic",
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-routed": null,
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-system-test": false,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "log-level": "error",
  "timestamp": 1473672066.691422,
  "envelope": {
    "transport": "smtp",
    "sender": "postmaster@mail.itvar.cz",
    "sending-ip": "209.61.151.224",
    "targets": "redakce@itvar.cz"
  },
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "***@gmail.com",
      "message-id": "20160912092103.8512.76522.0B575386@mail.itvar.cz",
      "from": "redakce@itvar.cz",
      "subject": "Tvar / Objednávka předplatného poštou"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "***@gmail.com",
      "***@predplatne.cz",
      "***@itvar.cz",
      "***@gmail.com"
    ],
    "size": 20917
  },
  "recipient": "redakce@itvar.cz",
  "id": "***"
}
```

TLDR: `505 Your domain has no DNS/MX entries`

```
{
  "severity": "permanent",
  "tags": [],
  "storage": {
    "url": "https://so.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/mail.itvar.cz/messages/***",
    "key": "***"
  },
  "delivery-status": {
    "tls": true,
    "mx-host": "ax.virusfree.cz",
    "attempt-no": 1,
    "description": null,
    "session-seconds": 1.5925419330596924,
    "code": 553,
    "message": "553 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist (#5.7.1)",
    "certificate-verified": true
  },
  "recipient-domain": "predplatne.cz",
  "event": "failed",
  "campaigns": [],
  "reason": "generic",
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-routed": null,
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-system-test": false,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "log-level": "error",
  "timestamp": 1473672065.693317,
  "envelope": {
    "transport": "smtp",
    "sender": "postmaster@mail.itvar.cz",
    "sending-ip": "209.61.151.224",
    "targets": "***@predplatne.cz"
  },
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "***@gmail.com",
      "message-id": "20160912092103.8512.76522.0B575386@mail.itvar.cz",
      "from": "redakce@itvar.cz",
      "subject": "Tvar / Objednávka předplatného poštou"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "***@gmail.com",
      "***@predplatne.cz",
      "***@itvar.cz",
      "***@gmail.com"
    ],
    "size": 20933
  },
  "recipient": "***@predplatne.cz",
  "id": "ZKO8IRlbQgqDZ-nrxn0tKg"
}
```

TLDR: `553 sorry, your envelope sender domain must exist (#5.7.1)`

### Context

To complicate things further, the domain http://itvar.cz stays in hands of the [previous webdesigner / hosting company](http://satoya.cz). That is because the old web of my client is essentially nonmigratable (as I was told) and still needed to work on http://old.itvar.cz.

That means, that:

1. `www` requests are transfered to [my web](http://itvar.cz) with the new hosting and its friendly provider
2. everything else stays with the old provider
3. I can't personally configure anything, I can only send instructions.

I've sent the logs to the old provider and he essentially told me, that this is a problem of Mailgun. To my very limited knowledge of DNS configuration it does not appear so.

### Questions

1. Is this really problem on Mailgun or the old provider configured DNS badly and I should press him more.
2. Can the problem lie with the sender "redakce@itvar.cz"? This email address exists, but it is, again, managed by the old provider, so I do not know much about it.
3. Do you see anything else that can cause the problem?
4. **edited**: The old provider noticed this field in the logs: `Default SMTP Login` > `postmaster@mail.itvar.cz`. This email address did not exist on the domain `mail.itvar.cz`. Could that be an issue? He created the address and so far, the issue is not fixed.

### Apologies

If it's not clear already, I really know nothing about DNS configuration and domain setup. If that means, that I haven't provided neccessary information or (by the contrary) shared something sensitive, please let me know.

Those are some related questions I've found, but nothing seems to mention similar errors:

- [smtp relay only works on gmail accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/411708/smtp-relay-only-works-on-gmail-accounts)
- [Emails are not received on any email account except Gmail and Hotmail](https://serverfault.com/questions/285175/emails-are-not-received-on-any-email-account-except-gmail-and-hotmail)
- [Emails are being rejected by some email providers](https://serverfault.com/questions/66029/emails-are-being-rejected-by-some-email-providers)

### EDIT: Issue is resolved

My domain fixed something on his end, so my order forms are working now. I am still waiting for his reply what exactly it was, but for now, it seems pretty apparent, that the problem was with the domain DNS configuration.

Once I will know more, I will answer my question myself.

Comment: Note that mail.itvar.cz has no A record.

Comment: According to a quick google, that is something that the domain owner (not me) should set to DNS records of the domain, right?

Comment: Whoever has access to change DNS records would make that entry.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to hear. I will presure the owner of domain more.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its edited body implies it lacks details to be properly answered by anyone but OP.